# Sporadic Windows fatal error on Github Python CI (may be joblib related)

Tags: python, windows, pytest, joblib, github-ci

I'm getting sporadic fatal errors for my Github CI on windows-latest, python version v3.11. While pytest is running, I get this error:

```
Windows fatal exception: code 0x80000003
```

[Link to example.](https://github.com/FastTrackiverse/fasttrackpy/actions/runs/8396683727/job/22998568139#step:6:43)

But, it doesn't *always* happen. I reran this failing job (no changes to the code in between) and it passed. [Link to the failure point on a re-run.](https://github.com/FastTrackiverse/fasttrackpy/actions/runs/8396683727/job/23158074365#step:6:44)

I'm *pretty* sure this is due to improvements I made to parallelization with joblib. The tests that are running when the fatal error occur involve [the code in this file in this PR.](https://github.com/FastTrackiverse/fasttrackpy/pull/64/files#diff-9b883f856218d65f7fb65316bbeafdbceaceefe116540bf04ae2e5803bda93f1)

Very roughly, the relevant code is:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from joblib import Parallel, cpu_count, delayed
#...
n_jobs = cpu_count()
arg_list = [
   ## kwargs dicts
]

@delayed
def get_candidates(args_dict):
   # stuff
   return result

candidate_list = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)(
  get_candidates(args_dict=arg) for arg in tqdm(arg_list)
)
```

In case it's relevant, [this is the test that's running](https://github.com/FastTrackiverse/fasttrackpy/blob/dev/tests/test_patterns/test_audio_textgrid.py) when the fatal exception occurs.

Any insight would be appreciated!